# windows service not hitting timmer1_Elapsed while debuggin using C#

Tags: c#, windows-services

I've following code snippet for windows service and it is not hitting `timer1_Elapsed` which is the main function to execute my logic. I've gone through the code using debugging. I would like to seek suggestions from experts.

```
public partial class myService : ServiceBase
{
public myService()
{
InitializeComponent();
if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists("myService Source"))
{
System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource(
"myService Source", "myService Log");
}
eventLog1.Source = "myService Source";
eventLog1.Log = "myService Log";
}

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
eventLog1.WriteEntry("myService service started on " + DateTime.Now.ToString());


System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();

System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();

string ProcessHour = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProcessHour"];
int intProcessHour = Convert.ToInt32(ProcessHour);

DateTime dtNow = DateTime.Now;

if (dtNow.Hour < intProcessHour)
{
DateTime dtToday = DateTime.Today;
DateTime dtStartDateTime = dtToday.AddHours(Convert.ToDouble(ProcessHour));
System.TimeSpan diff = dtStartDateTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
timer1.Interval = diff.TotalMilliseconds;
timer1.Start();
}
else
{
DateTime dtToday = DateTime.Today;
DateTime dtStartDateTime = dtToday.AddDays(1).AddHours(Convert.ToDouble(ProcessHour));
System.TimeSpan diff = dtStartDateTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
timer1.Interval = diff.TotalMilliseconds;
timer1.Start();
}
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
eventLog1.WriteEntry("myService service stopped on " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
}

private void timer1_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)

{
try
{

timer1.Stop();

string StartTimer, EndTimer;
StartTimer = DateTime.Now.ToString();
eventLog1.WriteEntry("myService timer1_Elapsed begin on " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
/*Some Logic*/
}

catch (Exception ex)
{

}

}
}
```

**Edit**
InitializeComponent() does contain that function but still unable to make a hit.

```
private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.eventLog1 = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog();
            this.timer1 = new System.Timers.Timer();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.eventLog1)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.timer1)).BeginInit();
            // 
            // timer1
            // 
            this.timer1.Enabled = true;
            this.timer1.Interval = 60000;
            this.timer1.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.timer1_Elapsed);
            // 
            // myService
            // 


 this.ServiceName = "myService";
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.eventLog1)).EndInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.timer1)).EndInit();

    }
```

Comment: Does the Constructor myService() ever get called?

Comment: Have a look at this NuGet package - https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceProcess.Helpers/.  @Shodan is right though

Comment: Corrections:The constructor is not called by the service.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you did it in the designer (so maybe it's into `InitializeComponent()`), you seem like you're missing to attach the event to `timer1`

```
timer1.Tick += timer1_Elapsed;
```

This should make the code work like you expect

If even this doesn't work, consider using the class `System.Timers.Timer`. Here's a reference that might help you understand the differences between Timer classes
https://web.archive.org/web/20150329101415/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx

Comment: It is there in InitializeComponent().. I've updated the code snippet with InitializeComponent().